# How to turn off "Always run as administrator"/ "Run this program as an administrator" on Windows 10/11 with CMD or PowerShell? Is this Possible

Tags: windows-10, powershell, cmd.exe, window

Is this possible to turn off "Always run as administrator" on Windows 10/11 with CMD or PowerShell for any specific program?

I have to off "Run this program as an administrator". On multiple PC and applications. I'm trying to avoid manually changing this setting.

[image]

Comment: Its not always possible. If a program does something that requires administrative rights, it will ask to do so. If not, there is a setting that sets it on that you can turn off. Its either running it in compatibility mode Win XP or earlier, or always run as admin from the properties of the exe file.

Comment: Perhaps I am being thick.. but "Always run as administrator" is something I am not used to seeing.  You quote it so I am thinking that this exists in a dialog or something?  Do you mean the UAC popup when you run something from cmd or powershell that requires elevated privileges?

Comment: I am not trying to pick apart you question.  I am just trying to understand what you are asking for.

Comment: I update the post